# click on image to switch to another image colored with the average color of the first

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have this section with a gallery of images, i want to click on an image and switch that image with a second one, this second image should be monochrome, with the average color of the first image. can i achieve this withh css? or with javascript? or i need C# or other languages?

```html
<section class="gallery">
        <img src="http://juliecristobal.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/20180601_Emma_09_0509-copie.jpg" alt="image">
        <img src="http://juliecristobal.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/20180701_Schon__010127.jpg" alt="image">
        <img src="http://juliecristobal.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/SK_FW18_ADDITIONALPIC_06_WEB.jpg" alt="image">
        <img src="http://juliecristobal.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/20180415_Elodie_05_1176-2-copie-1.jpg" alt="image">
    </section>
```

Comment: You need JavaScript yes. You can rule out the other two as follows: 1) CSS affects the appearance of objects, it does not react to user events (with the odd exception like hover) or move objects to different locations or change their properties). 2) C# only runs on the server, not in the browser. Browsers can only understand JavaScript.

Comment: ok, and do you know some script to achieve it with JS?

Comment: I would look through this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas

Comment: not off the top of my head, no. This is not a free write-my-code service. If you've learnt some JS, researched what you want to do, tried to find examples of each task you're attempting, made some effort to try and code it, and then found a mistake or problem...that's when we'll step in and help. We're not going to either teach you JS, or provide you a free tutorial out of nowhere. We volunteer in our spare time, so we expect you to invest a little of your own time before asking for ours.

Comment: What do you mean by `with the average color of the first image`?

Comment: i mean the average of the RGB components

Comment: ADyson, i just asked if you knew something similar, i don't want nor need you to teach me anything, thanks for the help anyway